# I am having trouble while using CefSharp

Tags: nuget, cefsharp

I am trying to use CefSharp for MonacoEditor, but whenever I build the project it [says this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nj59L.png):

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error CefSharp.Common contains unmanaged resoures, set your project and solution platform to x86 or x64.

I tried updating cef.redist.x64 and cef.redist.x86, but it says it's "not compatible." Can someone help me?

Comment: I've never used CefSharp, but going to their homepage, they have [quickstart](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Quick-Start) guides, which include showing you how to set either x64 or x86. Did you try the quickstart guide?

Comment: No not yet, but I will try it. Thank you!

Comment: What version are you using? Don't try and upgrade `cef.redist` yourself, that won't work. To target `x86` or `x64` you must set the solution platform target.

Comment: It is okay if you can help me with that?

Comment: Please be specific when you ask for help, I don't know what that is.

Comment: You didn't answer my question either

Comment: So I managed to fix the problem with your help, thank you. Unfortunately now I get this:

Code generation for property 'Text' failed. Error was: 'Property accessor 'Text' on object 'monaco1' threw the following exception: 'Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.WinForms, Version=67.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=(I think I need to hide this idk)' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: When you install the packages a readme is opened https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/69/NuGet/Readme.txt#L12